# How secure are javascript browser-based games from third party hackers

Tags: javascript, security

If I placed a javascript game on my website and part of the game asked for user addresses (in order to refer to local landmarks for example) is it possible that some third party might be able to hijack my game to send the user addresses their way?

I understand that javascript is not very secure, but I'm also thinking that no one will be able to hijack my javascript code without hacking my site, so it's secure in that respect.

Am I being naive?

Just asking because I have an idea for a game that I'm trying to think through.

Comment: The hacker would only need to hijack the PC.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider your user's addresses to truly be a secret, then yes you probably have some work to do:

## XSS attacks

You need to be very careful about how you display user input. For example, if I say my name is `<script>alert('hello world')</script>`, are you actually going to print that out in the website? If so, can then insert their own JavaScript into your application. [Here's an example of an XSS attack](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) has more information. If attackers can insert custom JS, they can intercept secret user input like addresses or passwords or cookies.

## HTTPS

When your web server sends its message back to the user, the message doesn't go directly to the user's computer. It first goes through intermediate computers in a relay race. If attackers control one of the computers in the middle of the relay race, they can modify the server's message and insert their own JS. Once again, the attackers win. To circumvent this, you'll need [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), which is a protocol that among other things encrypts the message. You'll also need something called a certificate; [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) sells them affordably.

Note that the attacker doesn't have to be some corporation or government sitting miles away to control an intermediate computer. It could be someone running [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on your school campus' unencrypted Wi-Fi network, for example.

## But really

A better way to structure your web application is to never send the user address back to your server in the first place. One of the first rules of information security is that it's hard to get right; the more you can rely on other people's work the better. Instead, maybe keep a fixed list of landmarks in the JS code. Or use a public API provided by a service like Google Maps, which already runs over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer Hao.  I don't plan to collect the data, just manipulate it with js right in the user's browser window. (Like you suggest: keep a fixed list of landmarks in the JS code.) With everything operating via js right in the user's browser window, are there still vulnerabilities?

Comment: Plaintext HTTP is the thorn. Imagine I control an intermediate server. I could rewrite your JavaScript to automatically send me user input when the user types the address.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "intermediate server," since the data will be manipulated right in the webpage.  For example, here's a simple javascript tool that operates right in the browser: http://www.esqsoft.com/tools/dedupe-list.htm.  Can a hacker collect the lists people are deduping at that page?